# Create a fake NSManagedObjectContext for preview purposes?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want a "fake" preview `NSManagedObject` to display as an example. However, I don't want to have it cluttering up my regular context. Here's what I'm assuming could work:

- Create a new `NSManagedObjectContext` and store the preview `NSManagedObject` there

  ```
  let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
  let person = Person(moc, "Person Name")
  ```

  What happens to the new context in this case? Is it slowly filling up storage or will it get removed if no `save()` is called and the View removed?
- Remove the newly created `NSManagedObject` when leaving the view

  ```
   SomeView()
   .onDisappear() {
       moc.delete(person)
       PersistenceController.shared.save()
   }
  ```

  This might not work if the `.onDisappear()` function doesn't get called, e.g. when the user leaves the app while that particular view is still open.
- Add the fake preview `NSMangagedObject` to the regular context and filter it out everywhere else (probably the worst idea)
- Create a new global context only for fake `NSManagedObject`s

Not sure which of these options is best or if there's a better way I haven't thought of. Thanks :)

Comment: A better solution is to make your persistence store exists only in memory so that any objects created will be removed when the app is terminated. There is built in support for this in the generated persistence controller class if you create a new core data project in Xcode

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'll do that then, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I created a new PersistenceController in memory as Joakim Danielson suggested in the comments, but using it alongside my other context was causing crashes and error messages. Simply creating a new NSManagedObjectContext, however, worked fine.

It is not saved to my "real" context, either (Apple Documentation):

> Changes to managed
> objects are held in memory, in the associated context, until that
> context is saved to one or more persistent stores

```
let tempMoc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

Usage

```
let person = Person(tempMoc, "Person Name")
```

Comment: It's better to move any code that mutates Model data, manipulates it, fetches it, or anything that is not a _pure_ function, into a View Model and let the view render just plain (constant) data. A user's actions may be implemented by sending _actions_ to the view model (which are simply function values initialised by the parent). Mocking  a ViewModel and doing the dependency injection there is not only much more easier, but the only place where you should do it.